# Pulling in memberships to event participant reports

Tags: civievent, civireport

I have a requirement for a client to be able to include a participant's membership level and status into an event participant report. I've checked through the options in the report templates but none of them seem to include this. Is it something which is even possible or would it require creating something bespoke for them?

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something along these lines with SearchKit. You could search Contacts with required Contact Participants and with optional Contact Memberships and then create a display with the columns you want.

Comment: Perfect - thank you so much!